# Why is jqgrid formatoption "onClick" loading automatically and not when cell is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, jqgrid, onclick

Why is the onClick being called automatically and not when I click on the cell? I want to be able to click the cell, then load the page. Code:

```
    colNames:['Name','Status', 'Created On', 'Update By', 'Updated On', 'RetentionDays','ValidityTime','Edit'],
    colModel:[
              {  
                  name: 'name', width:100,editable: true, edittype:'select',

                  formatter: "dynamicLink",
                  "formatoptions":{"onClick":$( "#contents" ).load("jsp/consumers.jsp")},

                  xmlmap: function (obj) {
                      return $(obj).attr('name'); 
                  }

              },
```

EDIT:

$(document).ready(function () 
        {

```
calEventTypes(eventTypesUrl);
$("#eventsDiv").click(function(){        
    $('#eventsErrorDiv').css("visibility", "hidden");  
    $('#eventsErrorDiv').css("display", "none");       

});
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    hidegrid: false,            
    datatype: 'xmlstring',
    datastr : xmlData,
    colNames:['Name','Status', 'Created On', 'Update By', 'Updated On', 'RetentionDays','ValidityTime','Edit'],
    colModel:[
              {  
                  name: 'name', width:100,editable: true, edittype:'select',

                  formatter: "showlink", idName: null,
                    onClick: function (options) {
                        alert("It's clicked!\nI'm going to Google...");
                        window.location = "https://www.google.com/";

                  },

                  xmlmap: function (obj) {
                      return $(obj).attr('name'); 
                  }
              },
```

Answer (score 1):

The handler has to be wrapped in a function:

```
        "formatoptions":{"onClick": function() {
          $( "#contents" ).load("jsp/consumers.jsp");
        }},
```

Comment: When I do this with  formatter: "showlink", then my jsp link does not load and I am taken to "original URL + ?id=(rowId). I want to be able to navigate to the signified URL load, how can I make this happen?

Comment: @BellaWesley I don't know; I don't know anything about jqgrid.

Comment: @BellaWesley: The goal of `onClick` is just providing the `click` callback, which prevent the standard action of the link (`<a>` element). Your code *inside of* your `onClick` function have access to the information from the clicked row and you can assign your custom URL to `windows.location`. If you want to execute `$("#contents").load("jsp/consumers.jsp");` on click then the code from the answer will be correct. I posted you [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-showlink.htm) as an example.

Comment: @Oleg the demo is exactly what I want my jqgrid to do. When I use the code in Pointy's answer, nothing happens at all. I opened up the page source to the example you provided and tried to implement the formatoption code exactly how it appears (including idname null, onclick, alert, and window.location to google). Still, when I click on the text in the cell, I am redirected FROM: http://localhost:8080/ServiceAdmin/ TO: http://localhost:8080/ServiceAdmin/?id=5 (for example when the 5th row is clicked). I do not get to google from my code and I do not get the alert either.

Comment: @Oleg I will edit my question to show you more of my code.

Comment: @BellaWesley: Your code is wrong. You missing `formatoptions`. You should use `formatter: "showlink", formatoptions: {idName: null, onClick: function (options) {...})` instead of `formatter: "showlink", idName: null, onClick: function (options) {...}` which you use now.

Comment: @Oleg Oops- my mistake. Okay, after correcting the code, I am still not redirected to google. Now I am redirected to http://localhost:8080/ServiceAdmin/?null=6 (or whatever number row I choose)... Still not having any luck, the only thing that has changed is "id" in the URL is now "null"

Comment: @BellaWesley: Do you verified that you use **correct version of jqGrid**, which supports `onClick`? Free jqGrid 4.13.3 can be loaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), be used from [CDN](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs), be loaded from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid), from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid), [bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=free-jqgrid), [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfree-jqgrid), ...

Comment: @Oleg I ended up figuring it out by calling a function in custom formatter and placing the onclick in the href within the function being called. Also, I had to set href to #, just like the variables in the first column of your example were.